# Import multiple files in different folders and concatenate them, using format in Python

Tags: python, format

I have a folder with subfolders for each state, as follows:

[image]

Inside the subfolders there are multiple excel files of the same census, as follows:

[image]

As you can see, each file is called with the name of the module and the code of the state.

What I want to do is reading all files of the same module and concatenate them. I tried to replace the folder path with formats and dictionaries, but it's not working.

```
states = {'05ALABAMA','12CALIFORNIA', '15TEXAS', '20ARKANSAS','23NEWYORK'} 
id_states = {'05', '12', '15', '20', '23'}

for i in states, id_states:
    data = pd.read_excel(r'census\{}\CEN_S4_{}.csv'.format(states, id_states))
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The structure of your `for` loop is iterating over `states` and `id_states` as if they were 2 items in a list. If you were to `print(i)`, you would see that it simply spits out the contents of `states` and then `id_states`.

Without changing your code much, I would suggest modifying `states` and `id_states` to be lists, and then altering your loop to be something like `for i in range(len(states))` and then using `i` to index your lists. You can access the items in your lists by doing something like `states[i]`.

Comment: Wouldn't `enumerate` or `zip` be better alternatives?

Comment: I tried: 

for i in range(len(states)):
    
    data = pd.read_excel(r'census\{}\CEN_S4_{}.csv'.format(states, id_states)) but it didn't work